# Elasticsearch Error: [parsing_exception] [match_phrase] query does not support [first_name]

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm running into an issue with the elasticsearch npm module. Here is my query:

```
try {
    const {
        hits: { hits }
    } = await client.search({
        index: "articles",
        body: {
            query: {
                match_phrase: {
                    authors: {
                        first_name: firstName,
                        last_name: lastName
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    hits.forEach(hit => {
        hit.type = TYPE_PHRASE;
    });

    return hits;
} catch (err) {
```

But this is returning an error,

```
Error: [parsing_exception] [match_phrase] query does not support [first_name]
```

I'm not sure what this means.. does this means I cannot search by `first_name`?

Here is the elasticsearch structure:

```
 [
      {
           "_score": 10.8702135,
           "_source": {
                "title": "Some title",
                "authors": [
                     {
                          "first_name": "John",
                          "last_name": "Smith",
                     },
                     {
                          "first_name": "Jane",
                          "last_name": "Doe",
                     },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) works on a single field. To search on multiple fields combine multiple match_phrase clauses using must/bool clause.

```
query: {
          bool: {
                     must: [
                               {
                                   match_phrase: {
                                                   authors.first_name: firstName
                                                 }                  
                                },
                                {
                                   match_phrase: {
                                                   authors.last_name: lastName
                                                 }                  
                                },
                            ]
                 }                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to make the first name and last name objects as a nested object. This will help you search first name and last name properly.

More details about the same and almost similar issue can be found in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html